# what is the equivalent in older versions. when i run in older versions, the app doesnt give me a large navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    } else {
       }
```

what is the equivalent of the above statement in older versions of IOS. when i run in older versions, the app doesnt give me a large navigation bar. what i am trying to achieve is to get a large navigation bar so that i can fit my custom view to it.Or is there any other way to increase the height of the navigation bar without hiding the content.

Comment: It won't work if the older version is below iOS-11. `prefersLargeTitles` is available for iOS-11 and above.

Comment: i know that buddy. How can i increase the height of navigation bar in older versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `navigationBar's` `height` programmatically using its `bounds` like so,

```
if let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 100.0))
}
```